# r - within-subject condition-dependent calculations

Tags: r, dplyr, difference

I need to perform within-subject, by-condition subtraction. Here's a sample of the data:

```
  subject    condition   target_resp.rt   
 1 1         a_un        1.0398901        
 2 1         b           0.6887729       
 3 1         a           0.7691720       
 4 1         a           1.0064900       
 5 1         a_un        0.8195999        
 6 2         a_un        0.8410320       
 7 2         b_un        0.8229311   
 8 2         b_un        0.9250839    
 9 2         b           1.0085750  
10 2         a           1.1406291     
11 3         b_un        0.5561039       
12 3         b           0.6022139       
13 3         b_un        0.8560688      
14 3         a           0.5886030       
15 3         a_un        0.5520449
```

For each subject, `target_resp.rt` should be subtracted according to the values of `condition`:

> - sum(a_un) - sum(a)
> - sum(b_un) - sum(b)

I tried doing the following using `dplyr`:

```
dataset %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(a.diff = sum(target_resp.rt[condition=="a_un"]) - sum(target_resp.rt[condition=="a"]), 
  b.diff = sum(target_resp.rt[condition=="b_un"]) - sum(target_resp.rt[condition=="b"]))
```

but it's not correct, as I get the same `diff` value for all conditions for each subject.

Comment: So e.g. for subject 1, same condition but different a_un values. What `a` do you subtract from which `a_un` for that subject?

Comment: it was supposed to be the sum of `a`'s - the sum of `a_un`'s. Sorry I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your approach. I think you might be confusing the *same `diff` value for all conditions* because you are using `mutate()` and getting a result for each entry ? Try using `summarise()` it will return one different `a` and `b` for each `subject`

Comment: yes, you're right!! thank you for the tip!